# GRUB Error while booting: You need to load the kernel first

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, uefi

I did a fresh install of Kubuntu 20.04.3 LTS a week back ago. I dual booted it with my Windows 10. I have a hybrid drive. 256 GB SSD and 1 TB HDD. From SSD I gave 30 GB for the root folder and from HDD I gave 540 GB for the Home Folder. This is the screen I get when I boot into my system: [GRUB Boot Loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZhYw.jpg)

Then I select Ubuntu from the list and it throws me this error:
[Error: Command Failed, you need to load the kernel first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6tIu.jpg)

I presses my power button and turned off my system and again turned it on. Then when I select Ubuntu from the list it boots perfectly fine. Sometimes it happens 1 time and sometimes it happens twice.

I have tried some solutions like disabling secure boot from UEFI settings but it did not work. I have also tried Ubuntu and Linux Mint before on my system, and it used to throw the same error. I also intstalled Zorin OS but it never threw this error. Please help.

Comment: Highlight Ubuntu in the Grub menu then press the key "e". This will display all boot options in a basic editor... Editing your original question above, and adding a screenshot or photo of those options will make troubleshooting a lot easier...

Comment: I have added the screenshot. Please click on the error message and the image will open

Comment: I didn't ask for the error messages but the kernel options that is specified in the GRUB config. They can be seen if you enter the editor instead of pressing enter to attempt booting your system.

Comment: I have a similar problem, still looking for a solution. In my case I choose UEFI settings from the GRUB menu, exit it without saving and then restart and Ubuntu boots. :shrug: I'm dual booting with a Windows 11 upgraded from 10.